# vector of objects won't compile

Tags: c++, class, types, vector

I've used vectors with objects hundreds of times but now seems it does not want to do anything with them. I keep getting a compile error "template argument for template type parameter must be a type" from this:

Note I'm using open frameworks

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "cLine.h"

using namespace std;

class testApp : public ofBaseApp{
    public:

        vector < cLine > lines; // Here is the vector of type cLine

        void setup();
        void update();
        void draw();

        void keyPressed(int key);
        void keyReleased(int key);
        void mouseMoved(int x, int y);
        void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button);
        void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button);
        void mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button);
        void windowResized(int w, int h);
        void dragEvent(ofDragInfo dragInfo);
        void gotMessage(ofMessage msg);
};
```

And the header file for cLine:

```
#ifndef aftermotion_cLine_h
#define aftermotion_cLine_h

#include <iostream>
#include "ofMain.h"

class cLine
{
public:

    int y;
    float thickness;

    cLine();
    cLine(const cLine &);
    cLine(float thinkness);

    void draw();
    void update();

};

#endif
```

Edit: I've tried #include , it hasn't changed a thing since its already part of the sdt library which itself is include from the "ofMain.h" file which is from the open frameworks library

Comment: You included "ofMain".  Did you try including `<vector>`?

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary parts of your example. e.g. The `TimeManager` include, the ofBaseApp inheritance. This reduces points of failure.

Comment: @pmr If I remove ofBaseApp the whole thing will break because its using open frameworkss

Answer (score 3):

You never `#include <vector>` in your header.  As such, `std::vector` isn't a known type.

Comment: but vector is part of the std include right, and thats included in the ofMain.h file which is part of openframeworks. I've tried including vector and using the std namespace to no avail

Comment: Do you mean the `using namespace std`? That does not do an include, and does not make the `vector` template available.

Comment: @TauraJGreig: I highly doubt that `ofMain.h` includes the entire C++ library.

Comment: but I've already used include <vector> and it does not change anything, I can replace cline with int and not include vector and it would run without a hitch.

Answer (score -1):

include vector.h

```
#include <vector>
```